# Настройка Apache/php на вывод страницы "частями"

Tags: apache, настройка, php

Имеется скрипт, который в цикле соединяется с разными серверами СУБД (СУБД находятся НЕ в локальной сети, ибо отсюда БОЛЬШИЕ задержки). Цикл состоит из 48 серверов СУБД. На каждой СУБД выполняются некие запросы. Результаты запросов, выводится в одну таблицу HTML страницы.

Вывод страницы происходит как бы "частями". То есть Web сервер Apache начинает выдавать страницу, когда php скрипт еще не до конца обработал все сервера СУБД. Есть ли какие настройки для регулирования такого вывода либо в Apache, либо в php? И

Насколько я понял, нужно смотреть директивы в php.ini

```
output_buffering = Off
implicit_flush = Off
```

и использование функций `flush(),ob_*()`. Я прав?

Answer (score 4):

Может, распараллелить? Выводите сразу таблицу, и скрипты, которые ajax-запросами заполнят ячейки, добавят строки, по мере поступления данных.

Сколько у вас независимых баз - столько под-запросов выполнит страница.
Либо, если все взаимосвязано, и нельзя показать всю таблицу, пока все данные не догрузились, то опять же, копить их в JS и на клиенте рендерить таблицу, когда все получены.

Comment: Спасибо. Как вариант тоже мог подойти, но сложнее в реализации. Я решил проблему функцией flush(). Просто до этого ни разу с подобными вещами не сталкивался и даже не догадывался, что можно управлять выводом...

ЗЫ а таблицу новые браузеры умеют прорисовывать сразу, не дожидаясь закрывающего </table>. Для этого нужно ширину полей в первой строке указать.... и еше что-то))

Answer (score 3):

[Цитата](http://i-novice.net/sokety-v-php/):
"А вызовом функции ob_implicit_flush мы говорим ему, что выводить строки с помощью echo нужно сразу при их выводе, а не после полной загрузки страницы, как это делается по-умолчанию."

Возможно поможет.

P.s. Может реально ввести медаль "По следа некромента" за ответ на очень старый вопрос?

Comment: @YGOR-CHAMIN я ответил только из-за того, что @ХешКод послал тебя на РутКод. Что в прицепе неправильно, т.к. нормальный веб-программист тратит где-то 15% времени на настройку.

Comment: 1. Кто вообще говорил про странность? А про "старый" было.   
2. О да, я просто маньяк по набиванию уважухи, френдов и лайков.  
Как бы возраст уже не тот.

Comment: @zenith ответь пожалуйста, просто очень интересно, а зачем ты ответил то на этот вопрос?
Я его задал 14 Авг 20:30, и того практически 2 месяца прошло!
не, ну честно, зачем?

Comment: Потому что мог ответить :)  
Честно.

Comment: @zenith Есть знак возрождение, он выдается, если отвечен старый вопрос с пятью голосами за. Это аналог предлагаемой медали.